# Change from sqlite3 to mysql on an existing project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I added gem mysql2 as suggested in other solutions and then tried creating the model, but I face the same error.

Below is my database.yml file and the error message. Also, please note that I am following a tutorial in which I need to first generate model and then run db:migrate.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql
  database: myrubyblog
  username: root
  password: root123
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myrubyblog
  username: root
  password: root123
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
  # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
  # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myrubyblog
  username: root
  password: root123
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myrubyblog
  username: root
  password: root123
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

---

```
sania@sania-Swift-SF314-52:~/myrubyblog$ rails g model category name:string
/home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:186:in `spec'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:356:in `active_record_configured?'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:273:in `disconnect_database'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:107:in `preload'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/sania/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Since the adapter is mysql2 shouldn’t the adapter in the database.yml also be mysql2 and not mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a line in your `config/database.yml` file to specify that the adapter is `mysql2` and not `mysql`.

`adapter: mysql2` instead of `adapter: mysql`

If your installation and bundling of `mysql2` is fine, it will work.

You might want to re-install `mysql2`. You can do it using the following command

`gem "mysql2"`

`bundle install`

Comment: Thank you. I did the above mentioned and after doing gem list, I could see 'mysql2' over there. But, I face this error while generating model-Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

your db adapter is wrong also your file has indentation problem, try this code

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: root123
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog_prod
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to use mysql database and I have my database created in mysql. Are mysql and mysql2 same or can be used interchangeably?

Comment: they both are different APIs, mysql2 is newer and faster

Comment: In order to stick to mysql, what should I do? get the gem mysql installed? and accordingly configure my mydatabase.yml?

Comment: I did as you mentioned in the answer and after doing gem list, I could see 'mysql2' over there. But, I face this error while generating model-Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: You need to add gem in your gemfile, add `gem 'mysql2'` in your gemfile and do bundle install

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by following below step:

1. gem 'mysql2' - Add this gem into your Gemfile
2. bundle install Or bundle update
3. adapter: mysql2 -Update you database.yml adapter

Hope this will help you :)